# What does Lockheed have to do to mark the end of the F-35's SDD?

Tags: military, aircraft-development, f-35, lockheed-martin

What does Lockheed Martin have to do to mark the end, or close out, the System Development and Demonstration phase of the F-35?

Comment: This is really a contracting question.  LM has to satisfy the SDD exit criteria that's defined in their contract with the F-35 program office.

Comment: The best indication of what remains to be done is given by the annual US DOT&E reports. The latest edition is here: http://www.dote.osd.mil/pub/reports/FY2017/pdf/dod/2017f35jsf.pdf I could summarise it to produce a swanky answer, but to be honest, that's quite an effort.

Comment: Are you asking about the A, B, or C model F-35?

Comment: I was under the assumption that the end of SDD would be a program event for all three simultaneously. Will each variant close out SDD separately?

Answer (score 1):

The clearest explanation I have found, comes from the Congressional Research Service ([www.crs.gov](http://www.crs.gov)), from RL30563.pdf:

> The F-35 is currently in low-rate initial production, with 280
>   aircraft delivered as of April 2018. At least 250 of those were in
>   U.S. service. Four to five aircraft are currently delivered each
>   month, with the production rate scheduled to increase to 120 per year
>   by 2019. In keeping with the acquisition plan that overlapped
>   development and production (known as “concurrency”), the F-35 was also
>   in system development and demonstration (SDD), with testing and
>   software development ongoing, from October 2001 until April 11, 2018.
>   The SDD phase will formally continue until the end of Initial
>   Operational Test and Evaluation, when a “Milestone C” full-rate
>   production decision will be made.

A copy of the full PDF is available here:

https://fas.org/sgp/crs/weapons/RL30563.pdf

We know from other sources that Initial Operational Test and Evaluation (IOT&E), will formally begin later this year, 2018.